# make background-image responsive for mobile-layouts but keep it in fixed position

Tags: html, css, background, fixed

How can i make my background-image of a section responsive to size changes of the browser? For example the Image is 1280x768 if the browser is in full-size-mode (2540x1440) as soon as i resize the window to a with lower than 1280 it should start shrinking but proportional. like i would resize it in adobe photoshop with proportion constraint on.

at the moment my html code looks as followed:

```
<!-- Header -->
<header class="masthead bg-head text-white text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-uppercase mb-0">My Name</h1>
    <img class="img-fluid" src="img/star-light.png" alt="">
    <h2 class="font-weight-light mb-0">Issue Solving</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

and the css-code im playing on for the last hour is:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  header{
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    background-image: url("../img/background-bern-4.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-top: 71px;
    padding-top: 96px;
    height: 25rem;
    width: 1280px;
  }
}
```

This looks as followed:
[image]

As soon as i start shrinking the browser to the same width as the picture it should star shrinking with it but proportionally. i somehow don't know any other tricks at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You don't need to do this in @media query :)

Second: You used a fixed width and height. This means it will be always this size no matter how much you resize browser.

So let's approach this problem without @media query and instead of fixed proportions we will use viewport units.

```
header{
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
    background-image: url("../img/background-bern-4.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: contain;
    margin-top: 71px;
    padding-top: 96px;
    height: 20vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
```

Changing it to vw and vh will make it responsive. You can add `max-width: 1280px`, so that your header won't be bigger than that on any large screen.